# UCF HSPT 2016 - Chomp Chomp

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I am having a lot of trouble finding an efficient solution to Problem #9 in the UCF HSPT programming competition. The whole pdf can we viewed [here](https://hspt.ucfprogrammingteam.org/hsptFiles/problemSet2016.pdf), and the problem is called "Chomp Chomp!".

Essentially the problem involves taking 2 "chomps" out of an array, where each chomp is a continuous chain of elements from the array and the 2 chomps have to have at least element between them that's not "chomped." Once the two "chomps" are determined, the sum of all the elements in both "chomps" has to be a multiple of the number given in the input. My solution essentially is a brute-force that goes through every possible "chomp" and I tried to improve the speed of it by storing previously calculated sums of chomps.

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class chomp {
    static long[] arr;

    public static long sum(int start, int end) {
        long ret = 0;
        for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret+=arr[i];
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static int sumArray(int[] arr) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static long numChomps(long[] arr, long divide) {
        HashMap<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        int k = 1;
        long numchomps = 0;
        while(true) {
            if (k > arr.length-2) break;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length -2; i++) {
                if ((i+k)>arr.length-2) break;
                String one = i + "";
                String two = (i+k) + "";
                String key1 = one + " " + two;
                long first = 0;
                if(map.containsKey(key1)) {
                    //System.out.println("Key 1 found!");
                    first = map.get(key1).longValue();
                } else {
                    first = sum(i, i+k);
                    map.put(key1, new Long(first));
                }
                int kk = 1;
                while(true){
                    if (kk > arr.length-2) break;
                    for (int j = i+k+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                        if((j+kk) > arr.length) break;
                        String o = j + "";
                        String t = (j+kk) + "";
                        String key2 = o + " " + t;
                        long last = 0;
                        if(map.containsKey(key2)) {
                            //System.out.println("Key 2 found!");
                            last = map.get(key2).longValue();
                        } else {
                            last = sum(j, j+kk);
                            map.put(key2, new Long(last));
                        }
                        if (((first+last) % divide) == 0) {
                            numchomps++;
                        }
                    }
                    kk++;
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
        return numchomps;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int length = in.nextInt();
            long divide = in.nextLong();
            in.nextLine();
            arr = new long[length];
            for(int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                arr[j] = (in.nextLong());
            }
            //System.out.println(arr);
            in.nextLine();
            long blah = numChomps(arr, divide);
            System.out.println("Plate #"+i + ": " + blah);
        }

    }

}
```

My code gets the right answer, but seems to take too long, especially for large inputs when the size of the array is 1000 or greater. I tried to improve the speed of my algorithm my storing previous sums calculated in a `HashMap`, but that didn't improve the speed of my program considerably. What can I do to improve the speed so it runs under 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

The first source of inefficiency is constant recalculation of sums. You should make an auxiliary array of partial sums `long [n] partial;`, then instead of calling `sum(i, i + k)` you may simply do `partial[i + k] - partial[i]`.

Now the problem reduces to finding indices `i<j<k<m` such that

```
    (partial[j] - partial[i] + partial[m] - partial[k]) % divide == 0
```

or, rearranging terms,

```
    (partial[j] + partial[m]) % divide == (partial[i] + partial[k]) % divide
```

To find them you may consider an array of triples `(s, i, j)` where `s = (partial[j] - partial[i]) % divide`, stable sort it by `s`, and inspect equal ranges for non-overlapping "chomps".

This approach improves performance from O(n<sup>4</sup>) to O(n<sup>2</sup> log n). Now you shall be able to improve it to O(n log n).

Comment: I have a hashmap to store previously calculated values why use an array?